# Remove resursion

Tags: php, recursion

I have a function and it works great. Let me ask is it possible to save functionality but remove recursion:

```
public static function GenerateNavHTML($items, $tabs = '') {
        $html = !strlen($tabs) ? 
                $tabs.'<ul class="dd-list">' : 
                $tabs.'<ul>';

        foreach($items as $item) {

            $item   = (object)$item;
            $html   .= $tabs."    ".'<li class="dd-item" data-id="'.(int)$item->id.'">';
            $html   .= '<div class="dd-handle">Drag</div>';
            $html   .= '<div class="dd-content">
                                <span class="title">'.(string)$item->name.'</span>
                                <div id="action" class="btn-group pull-right">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" title="Edit category" data-action="edit" data-id="'.(int)$item->id.'" data-category="'.(string)$item->name.'"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" title="Delete category and all nested categories" data-action="delete" data-id="'.(int)$item->id.'" data-category="'.(string)$item->name.'"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>';

            if(isset($item->children[0])) {
                $html .= self::GenerateNavHTML($item->children, $tabs."        ");
            }
            $html .= '</li>';
        }

        $html .= $tabs.'</ul>';
        return $html;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you looking to remove `recursion`?

Comment: Another point of view. Is it possible?

Comment: `recursion` allows this function to go infinitely deep into your list as long as their are child elements.  its the most elegant solution for this as with out recursion you would need to write a lot of `foreach` loops, ie if your list was 50 levels you would need 50 loops of the same code which is just silly.

Comment: I know that we can use while and each syntax for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using Queue for this. If I get it correctly, your $item can have multiple childrens and each of them would require similar processing(for loop etc). You can use SplQueue and put each item in queue as soon as you find them. here is the psuedo code:

```
$itemQ = queue of all top level items
foreach $item in $itemQ
      //do processing here
      if $item->children
          $itemQ.add( $item->children)
```